# Anonymous function in R

Tags: r, function

Using a dataset *w*, which includes a numeric column *PY*, I can do:

```
nrow(subset(w, PY==50))
```

and get the correct answer. If, however, I try to create a function:

```
fxn <- function(dataset, fac, lev){nrow(subset(dataset, fac==lev))}
```

and run

```
fxn(w, PY, 50)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'PY' not found

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of `subset`:

> **Warning**
>   This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

This rather obscure warning was very well explained here: [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

The final word is you can't use `subset` other than *interactively*, in particular, not via a wrapper like you are trying. You should use `[` instead:

```
fxn <- function(dataset, fac, lev) nrow(dataset[dataset[fac] == lev, , drop = FALSE])
```

or rather simply:

```
fxn <- function(dataset, fac, lev) sum(dataset[fac] == lev)
```

Comment: I read the linked page and Hadley's documentation; still can't make it work :(